# Приложение не работает при загрузке с Play Market, но работает стабильно при запуске через Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps-api, firebase, playmarket, google-services

Приложение взаимодействует с Firebase и google services, соответственно имеется файл google-services.json. Предполагаю проблема связана с ней. В частности ошибка выскакивает после попытки аутентификации через мобильный телефон(отправка смс с кодом на номер телефона). Далее сама код ошибки :

```
07-04 13:21:07.292 2872-12688/? E/Volley: [1511] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyC1Uz6ATRtZx_en5cR1o5VNnsVpyy0IDyE
07-04 13:13:15.610 2872-12304/? I/AuthChimeraService: Error description received from server: The Android package name and signing-certificate fingerprint, my.project.faq.findme and DAF5B744BA643591947DA26B2FBBEA8768D664E9, do not match the app restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions.
```

При попытке добавить ограничения в google api console'е (приложение для Android) выдает следующую ошибку :

```
07-04 13:13:15.610 2872-12685/? E/Volley: [1508] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode?alt=proto&key=AIzaSyC1Uz6ATRtZx_en5cR1o5VNnsVpyy0IDyE
07-04 13:13:15.610 2872-12304/? I/AuthChimeraService: Error description received from server: The Android package name and signing-certificate fingerprint, my.project.faq.findme and DAF5B744BA643591947DA26B2FBBEA8768D664E9, do not match the app restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions.
```

Возможно добавляя ограничение в google api consol, также следует изменить сам google-services.json файл? Или я мыслю не в том направлении? Повторюсь: 
Приложение стабильно работает при запуске с Android Studio. Информации по этому вопросу, к сожалению, не нашел. Есть идеи как это исправить?

Comment: Проверьте, что приложение с маркета и при запуске из студии имеют одинаковые пакеты и подписаны одинаковыми сертификатами. 

Может вы настроили проект в Firebase используя дебажный сертификат.

Comment: @RamilGabdrakhmanov в Firebase все в порядке с пакетом и сертификатом. А как это проверить в маркете, там же нет возможности добавить имя пакета и сертификат, туда же загружается сгенерируемый apk файл со студии? Хотя в маркете нашел графу 'Подписи приложений', там сертификат отличается от действительного, изменить нельзя, можно скачать сами сертификаты.

Comment: Еще в графе 'Подписи приложений' у меня включен сервис Google Play App Signing. Может тут что-то не так?

Comment: То есть у вас есть сертификат для загрузки приложений и потом Google Play переподписывает ваше приложение другим. 

Так вот, вам нужно указать в Firebase хэш того сертификата, которым подпишет приложение Google Play

Comment: @RamilGabdrakhmanov Действительно, в этом была ошибка. Спасибо, проблема решена!